# Stopping exploits based on Reversing TCP

Tags: tcp

One of the most common exploits on msf, reverse tcp by buffer overflow i guess is my concern. Can i, by any means stop of manage my tcp ports to deny giving access to rhosts and become safe from this type of attack?

Answer (score 1):

There is not such thing as an exploit based on reverse TCP, reverse TCP is only the way in which attacker get's a communication channel with the exploited host.

You can try to minimize the chances that an attacker opens a reverse connection using outbound firewall rules that prevents your servers to access ports that they don't need. Even if your server needs to have ports opened and services published, that does not means that has to have irrestricted access to the outside world, I would recommend blocking everything except maybe SMTP if it is a mail server and if you need HTTP/HTTPS do it through a proxy. This would prevent your server to open a reverse connection to serve a remote shell to the attacker's IP address. Also, most Intrusion Prevention Systems would raise an alert when they see abnormal outbound traffic.

The best would be of course, **prevent that the exploited service is compromised in first place**, by following the hardening guides of the vendor, using service accounts with the minimun required privilege to run those services, and keeping your software up to date. Almost every exploit module that you will find in MSF is already patched by the vendor by the time that it is published.